# Connect ADB over wifi

Tags: java, android, android-studio, usb, adb

Is there any way to connect adb over wifi with my android phone. I don't have any USB cable, as there is way to do this like here:- [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless)

But for doing this i need to connect my phone to pc with USB first but my mobile has some problem it was not connecting to my pc with USB so any way to do it without using usb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: There is no particular correct answer, i already tried there.

Answer (score 1):

you either need to have a device connected or a running emulator for using following command:

adb tcpip 5555

what if you don't have usb cable for some reason?
what to do?
here's a solution.
If you run an android emulator, above command will work but draw back is , it take too much time (few minutes to be specific).

So what's the fastest solution,

Well, install [AnBox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjigtv73fToAhWC7XMBHcslArUQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fanbox.io%2F&usg=AOvVaw3dLbepvSl7Rg6U4B-jhCtZ).
Its also an emulator which opens much faster, within few seconds.
now, you can run above command:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

to start adb in tcpip mode

use below command to connect to your android phone over wifi

```
adb connect <ip address of android phone>:5555
```

if you want to control it over wifi from laptop use [scrcpy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiahJPo3vToAhUE93MBHWKcCqMQFjABegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FGenymobile%2Fscrcpy%2Freleases&usg=AOvVaw0TmdOVukq9nAxpWwELFI5t)

```
scrcpy -s <ip address of android phone>:5555
```

Answer (score 1):

With the launch of Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1), a new feature **ADB over Wi-Fi** is included, to simplify flow to connect to your Android 11 and higher devices over Wi-Fi for deployment and debugging using ADB. After you [enable debugging over Wi-Fi](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+) on your device, select the **Pair using Wi-Fi** action in the **Physical** tab of the new **Device Manager** to open the pairing wizard. Then follow the steps provided to pair to a device connected over the same network.
[To learn more.](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless-adb-android-11)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But to do this you need a rooted android device. After that simply download Wifi adb from google play store. Link given below

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en

Then go to your sdk folder/platform tools in the command prompt. Then type adb connect 192.168.xx.xx:xxxx , where xx is the no. shown in the Wifi ADB app. That's it. We also use it as Most of the times USB cables get worn after some usage.

Comment: I don't have rooted android device.

Comment: You need to have a rooted device for wifi debugging via 3rd party software, please consider rooting your device

Comment: No, you don't need a rooted device, I have an android tv which is not rooted, and I can still debug over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installing your device driver and adb service and

1- is activated `USB debugging` in android device

`setting -> (system)-> developer options -> USB debugging` and must be could to see your device when you connected by USB port ( by this command : adb devices)

so when you connected by USB follow this Commands :

2- in some android versions need to select `Transfer File` option in the `Use USB To` from `Connected devices`

```
1-stay connect via USB
2-connect to your WIFI network (computer and mobile device both)
3-ping DeviceIP (must be have ping to your device)

4 - adb kill-server
5 - adb usb
6 - adb tcpip 5556 (if you are using docker container it may need different port number like 5037)
7 - adb connect "yourDeviceIP:5556"
8 - devices (must be see two device names , one of them is by deviceIP:5556)
9-unplug USB cable
```

then it's Done! and you could to test your app

[ref: JDev answer](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/632455)

Comment: some examples to ping DeviceIP in linux: https://linuxhint.com/ping_command_ubuntu_20-04/